Add dynamic keys and dynamic values to a javascript object
I'd like to send back an object like this from the following function below in typescript:
    marked = {
      '2024-08-21': {
        dots:[food, recycling]
      },
      '2024-08-22': {
        dots:[food, recycling]
      }
    }

This is what I have so far.
function addKeysAndValuesDynamically(days: string[]): any {
  var marked = {};
  const food = {key: 'food', color: 'brown'};
  const recycling = {key: 'recycling', color: 'green'};
  days.forEach((day: string) => {
    marked[day]['dots'] = food, recycling;
  });
  return marked;
}

var days: string[] = ['2024-08-21', '2024-08-22'];
var marked = addKeysAndValuesDynamically(days);
console.log(`marked = ${marked}`);

I'm expecting it to return the object 'marked' as seen above but I get an error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'dots' of undefined.

I'm assuming you've just came to typescript from javascript since you are trying to avoid using types, this is a way you can do it using interfaces:
interface KeyColor {
    key: string;
    color: string;
}

interface Marked {
    [day: string]: {
        dots: [KeyColor, KeyColor]
    }
}

function addKeysAndValuesDynamically(days: string[]): Marked {
  const marked: Marked = {};
  const food = {key: 'food', color: 'brown'};
  const recycling = {key: 'recycling', color: 'green'};
  days.forEach((day: string) => {
    marked[day] = { dots: [food, recycling] }
  });
  return marked;
}

var days: string[] = ['2024-08-21', '2024-08-22'];
var marked = addKeysAndValuesDynamically(days);
console.log(marked); // you have to log it this way to view object properties

Playground link
